# rails passing non user editable parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

learning rails, and playing with scaffolding.

I've:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :status)
end
```

And

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
end
```

I want to pass to db non user editable parameters like uid and user_id.

How would I do that?

Comment: Where are those parameters? in params?

Comment: To pass `user_id`: `@project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)`

Comment: @RSB they are nowhere, I want to manually drop them in. uid for example SecureRandom.hex(6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign them manually in the controller

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  @project.user_id = # the user id you want to assign
  @project.uid = SecureRandom.hex(6)
  @project.save
end
```